Carousel in Nextjs using Framer-motion
Hi there!
I'm working on Nextjs+typescript and using framer-motion for animations. I'm trying to create this Carousel for quite some time now and I'm stuck. This is what it should look like:
www.hover.dev/components/features#collapse-card-features
This effect is like stacking up cards one by one. The first card shall remain static and will act as the base for other cards.
Each card will mount on top of the base card on click. At the same time, the subsequent cards (cards behind the mounting card) will shift to cover the place left by the mounting card. These two animations will work simultaneously. At last when all cards are iterated, we will get a stack of cards. then, on click again, the stacked cards will shift one by one to take there initial place.
This can be visualized as a queue of people where when a person is added to the queue everyone takes a step back and when someone leaves the queue, everyone takes a step forward to cover the space left behind.
The code I've written is just working for the first card only. I'm still learning framer-motion and animations in general are quite difficult.
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  ChevronRightCircle,
  ChevronLeftCircle,
  LucideAward,
  LucideHandCoins,
} from "lucide-react";
import { animate, motion } from "framer-motion";

type Direction = "left" | "right";

const HealthCarousel: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState<Direction>("right");
  const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false);
  const [hasAnimationCompleted, setHasAnimationCompleted] = useState(false);

  const totalCards = 5;

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (currentIndex < totalCards - 1) {
      setDirection("right");
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
      setIsAnimating(true);
    }
  };
  const handlePrev = () => {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      setDirection("left");
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
      setIsAnimating(true);
    }
  };

  console.log(currentIndex, direction, isAnimating, hasAnimationCompleted);

  return (
    <div className="no-scrollbar block relative w-full overflow-hidden overflow-y-scroll bg-gradient-to-276-1">
      <section className="overflow-hidden px-4 pt-8 pb-10">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-6xl">
          {/* buttons */}
          <div className="mb-8 flex justify-end gap-4  ">
            <div className="flex gap-0 ">
              <button
                onClick={() => animate(".card", { x: 0 })}
                className="h-fit carouselbtn p-4 rounded-full text-2xl text-white  "
              >
                <ChevronLeftCircle strokeWidth={1} size={52} />
              </button>
              <button
                onClick={() => animate(".card", { x: "-95%" })}
                className="h-fit p-4 carouselbtn rounded-full text-2xl text-white"
              >
                <ChevronRightCircle strokeWidth={1} size={52} />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* static first card */}
          <div className="flex gap-4">
            <div className="relative flex min-h-[250px] w-10/12 max-w-lg shrink-0 flex-col justify-between overflow-hidden p-8 shadow-lg md:w-3/5 rounded-lg bg-white">
              <div className="absolute right-16 top-10 scale-150">
                <LucideAward />
              </div>
              <h3 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-bold">Expert Guidance</h3>
              <p>
                Get clear, helpful advice from our experienced professionals. We
                guide you with easy-to-follow steps to manage your health
                effectively.
              </p>
            </div>
            {/* animating cards */}
            <motion.div
              initial="initial"
              exit="exit"
              custom={0}
              style={{ zIndex: currentIndex === 0 ? 9 : 2 }}
              onAnimationComplete={() => {
                setIsAnimating(false);
                setHasAnimationCompleted(true);
              }}
              className={`relative card bg-white flex min-h-[250px] w-10/12 max-w-lg shrink-0 flex-col justify-between overflow-hidden p-8 shadow-lg md:w-3/5 rounded-lg "
                `}
            >
              <div className="absolute right-16 top-10 scale-150">
                <LucideHandCoins />
              </div>
              <h3 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-bold">Affordable Plans</h3>
              <p>
                Our plans are designed to be budget-friendly while still
                providing top-notch care. Get high-quality health management
                without breaking the bank.
              </p>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div
              initial="initial"
              animate={
                isAnimating ? "animate" : hasAnimationCompleted ? "animate" : ""
              }
              exit="exit"
              custom={1}
              style={{ zIndex: currentIndex === 1 ? 10 : 2 }}
              onAnimationComplete={() => {
                setIsAnimating(false);
                setHasAnimationCompleted(true);
              }}
              className={`relative bg-white card flex min-h-[250px] w-10/12 max-w-lg shrink-0 flex-col justify-between overflow-hidden p-8 shadow-lg md:w-3/5 rounded-lg "
                `}
            >
              <div className="absolute right-16 top-10 scale-150">
                <LucideHandCoins />
              </div>
              <h3 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-bold">Affordable Plans</h3>
              <p>
                Our plans are designed to be budget-friendly while still
                providing top-notch care. Get high-quality health management
                without breaking the bank.
              </p>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div
              initial="initial"
              animate={
                isAnimating ? "animate" : hasAnimationCompleted ? "animate" : ""
              }
              custom={2}
              style={{ zIndex: currentIndex === 2 ? 12 : 2 }}
              onAnimationComplete={() => {
                setIsAnimating(false);
                setHasAnimationCompleted(true);
              }}
              className={`relative rounded-lg card flex min-h-[250px] w-10/12 max-w-lg shrink-0 flex-col justify-between overflow-hidden p-8 shadow-lg md:w-3/5 bg-black text-white"`}
            >
              <h3 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-bold">500+ integrations</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem
                explicabo nobis officia, nostrum eligendi accusamus unde ad
                cumque, magnam deleniti adipisci fugiat facere. Veniam?
              </p>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div
              initial="initial"
              animate={
                isAnimating ? "animate" : hasAnimationCompleted ? "animate" : ""
              }
              custom={3}
              style={{ zIndex: currentIndex === 3 ? 14 : 2 }}
              onAnimationComplete={() => {
                setIsAnimating(false);
                setHasAnimationCompleted(true);
              }}
              className={`relative flex card min-h-[250px] w-10/12 max-w-lg shrink-0 flex-col justify-between overflow-hidden p-8 shadow-lg md:w-3/5  bg-white"`}
            >
              <h3 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-bold">Modern tooling</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Minima, saepe quo!
              </p>
            </motion.div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HealthCarousel;

Help me Out!! Thanks!

tbh I wrote most of the logic using gpt. It is really difficult to get this animation effect to work.
